# ¿Cómo limpiar el terminal C ANSI con Linux?

Tags: c, linux, terminal

Me gustaría saber cómo limpiar el terminal ejecutando un programa de C en Linux.

```c
    printf ("\033[2J\033[1;1H");
```

Gracias de antemano por las respuestas y sugerencias.

Comment: Pareciera que es la forma estándar, [usada comúnmente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006262/clearing-output-of-a-terminal-program-in-linux-c) por [ahí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42523202/how-to-clear-my-previous-output-in-linux-terminal-using-c). Lo único sería probar si `fflush(stdout);` te sirva

Comment: Tambien podrías usar ```system("clear");```, aunque creo que es mucho más lento que tan sólo usar printf

Comment: Esta pregunta está llamando a responder basado en la opinión personal (lo que es mejor para uno, puede no ser igual que lo que es mejor para otro) y por tanto está fuera del formato del sitio. Te invito a leer [ask], quizás puedas cambiar la pregunta para evitar las respuestas basadas en opiniones.

Comment: Yo no quitaría _el código_ que estás usando; en su encarnación actual queda aún más orientada a buscar opiniones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método más Unix-y sería

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <term.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  tgetent (NULL, getenv("TERM")); // una vez por el programa
  tputs(tgetstr ("cl", 0), 1, putchar);
}
```

Necesitas añadir `-lcurses` a tu comando de compilación

```
gcc -o ejemplo ejemplo.c -lcurses
```

Un programa real habría usado el manejo de errores. Este ejemplo no tiene nada. `getenv` y `tgetent` podrían fallar.

Si no compila con `-lcurses` instalar (para Ubuntu o Debian):

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
```

Hay muchas capacidades que es posible utilizar de esta manera, por ejemplo moviendo el cursor o usando colores, usando nombres mnemotécnicos como `cl` en lugar de códigos ANSI como `\033[2J`.

Para más información, ver https://www.gnu.org/software/termutils/manual/termcap-1.3/html_chapter/termcap_2.html (la página es muy antigua y no utiliza el estándar de C).

Comment: el problema de usar curses es que presuponen borrar la salida de pantalla, pero si estas en un terminal remoto, y quieres borrar el cliente que esta conectado, ese borrado intenta borrar el de servidor. Lo mejor en este caso seria mas utilizar codigos ANSI (como expone @Emm en su pregunta)

Comment: @Jakala Lo siento, no entiendo. ¿Qué significa "borrar el de servidor"? Curses genera los mismos códigos que generarías manualmente. No importa si se encuentras en un terminal local o remoto. Programas de curses funcionan con terminal remoto sin problema.